# Solidity Advanced Transparent Proxy pattern

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts

[image: Advanced? Transparent Proxy Pattern]

1. **Proxy contract** - The contract users are calling to use current implementation
2. **Admin Proxy Contract** - Contarct to Update Current Implementation or current Structure Model
3. **Implementation Contract** (where all the logic functions stored) that we can replace
4. **Structure Model Contract** (where we store all structs) that we can replace
5. **Storage contact** that is immutable and where all application data stored (mappings, arrays and so on)

So my question - is thisa good way to manage contracts and is it possible to implement? and if it is, where can I read the information or see a similar implementation

Comment: I'd say that it is a common implementation for complex contracts.